Error while creating model valuations using ModelEvaluationClassificationOp
I am encountering an issue while attempting to access data in the ModelEvaluationClassificationOp which is a pre-built gcp component. The error message I am receiving is:
"LookUpInode: input/output error, Error in iterating through objects: storage: bucket doesn't exist."
Here are the details of the relevant code snippet:
enter image description here
enter image description here
ModelEvaluationClassificationOp expects two GCS input paths (ground_truth_gcs_source and predictions_gcs_source), but I am encountering difficulties accessing the specified buckets.
ground_truth_gcs_source: list[str] = ["gs://trk-ai-models/sklearn-income-pred-model/income_classification_ml_metadata/input_predcition_data/gcs_groundtruth.jsonl"]
predictions_gcs_source: dsl.Input[system.Artifact] = "gs://trk-ai-models/sklearn-income-pred-model/income_classification_ml_metadata/output_predictions_data/prediction-test_income_model-2024_03_19T06_00_04_089Z"
I have verified that the specified buckets and respective files in Cloud Storage exist and are accessible.
reference snippet : https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/v1/model_evaluation/evaluation_automl_tabular_pipeline.py#L72
please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue or suggest troubleshooting steps?
